# Action fires more than once on second load

Tags: javascript, jquery, twitter-bootstrap, modal-dialog

### PROBLEM

I have a modal that I use app wide. This modal's content and confirm action changes depending on what is clicked.

The first time this modal launches, everything is fine and dandy, and the modal's confirm only fires once.

Any other time, the modal fires the confirm action 3 times.

### MY CODE

The modal and button in my HTML page:

```
<div class="modal fade" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" id="confirmationModal">
    <div class="modal-dialog modal-sm">
        <div class="modal-content">
            <div class="modal-header"></div>
            <div class="modal-body"></div>
            <div class="modal-footer">
                <button class="btn btn-danger" data-event="click" data-action="closeModal">Cancel</button>
                <button class="btn btn-success" data-event="click">Confirm</button>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
<i class="fa fa-trash linked-fa red-fa" data-confirm="temDelete" data-event="click" data-id="template" data-header="Confirm Delete" data-body="Are you sure you want to delete Template?" data-action="showModal"></i>
```

And my Javascript (well actually, JQuery)

```
$(document).ready(function(e) {
    setEventListeners();
});

function setEventListeners() {
    // Find all elements with a data-action attribute
    $('[data-action]').each(function() {

        // Set the callback to the action
        // Link the event to the callback
        var theCallback = $(this).data('action');
        var theEvent = $(this).data('event');

        // If theEvent == 'load', do it immediately
        if(theEvent == 'load') {
            executeFunctionByName(theCallback,this,$(this));
        } else {
            // When the event fires, do the callback
            $(this).on(theEvent,function(e) {
                executeFunctionByName(theCallback,window,$(this),e)
            });
        }
    });
}

function executeFunctionByName(functionName,context) {
    // I actually have no freakin idea what this does

    // Google made me copy paste it.
    var args = [].slice.call(arguments).splice(2);
    var namespaces = functionName.split(".");
    var func = namespaces.pop();

    for(var i = 0; i < namespaces.length; i++) {
        context = context[namespaces[i]];
    }

    if(typeof context[func] !== 'undefined') {
        return context[func].apply(this, args);
    } else {
        console.log('Function not found.');
    }
}

function showModal(element) {

    // Get and set the body and header of the modal
    $('#confirmationModal .modal-header').html(element.data('header'));
    $('#confirmationModal .modal-body').html(element.data('body'));

    // Transfer all data fields from the clicked element to the confirm button in the Modal
    $.each(element.data(),function(i,v) {
        if(i != 'event') {
            if(i == 'confirm') { i = 'action'; } // If the data is confirm, change it to action, as this is the modal's action
            $('#confirmationModal .modal-footer .btn-success').attr('data-' + i,v);
        }
    });

    setEventListeners();
    // Set the page listeners and show the modal
    $('#confirmationModal').modal('show');
}

function closeModal() {
    $('#confirmationModal').modal('hide');
}

function temDelete() {
    $('.actionsfired').append('Delete Fired<br>');
    closeModal();
}
```

I've created a [fiddle that replicates this behaviour](https://jsfiddle.net/Low6d2da/2/).

### QUESTION

How can I prevent the confirm action from being fired 3 times?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So I fixed it by making a `removePageListeners` function.

```
function removePageListeners() {
    $('[data-action]').each(function() {
        var theEvent = $(this).data('event');

        $(this).off(theEvent);
    });
}
```

I call this right after I open the modal.

Updated [fiddle here](https://jsfiddle.net/Low6d2da/4/).

Answer (score 0):

You call 
setEventListeners() method every time showModal is called.

In setEventListeners method

```
$(this).on(theEvent,function(e) {
     executeFunctionByName(theCallback,window,$(this),e)
});
```

This line registeres event again and again. If you register a callback to an event n times. callback is triggered for n times when one event occurs.

For quick solution;

remove setEventListeners() method call from showModal()

Comment: But then the modals actions wont fire. Every time the modal loads, it will change the confirm buttons action.